# WordPress post shows only the content of the first post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I want to create a WordPress theme from an HTML template which uses jquery to animate the posts opening from the grid of all the posts published on the main page. 
I managed to get the posts grid on the main page like this:

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => $count,
  'paged'          => $paged,
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>




        <a class="grid__item" href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>">
  <!--Post data-->
                        <h1 class="title title--preview"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                        <div class="loader"></div>
                        <span class="category"><p><?php echo excerpt(10); ?></p></span>

                        <div class="meta meta--preview">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array( 'class'=> 'meta__avatar')); ?>
                            <span class="meta__date"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
                            <span class="meta__reading-time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2 min read</span>
                        </div>

</a>


<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and the inside content of the post like this:

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => $count,
  'paged'          => $paged,
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

  <section class="content">
    <div class="scroll-wrap">

            <article class="content__item">
                            <span class="category category--full">Life &amp; Death</span>
                            <h2 class="title title--full"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                            <div class="meta meta--full">
                                <!--<img class="meta__avatar" src="img/authors/4.png" alt="author04" />-->
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array( 'class'=> 'meta__avatar')); ?>
                                <span class="meta__author"><?php the_author(); ?></span>
                                <span class="meta__date"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
                                <span class="meta__reading-time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2 min read</span>
                                <span class="meta__misc meta__misc--seperator"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> 7 comments</span>
                                <span class="meta__misc"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> 12 favorites</span>
                                <nav class="article-nav">
                                    <button><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> <span>Previous</span></button>
                                    <button><span>Next</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
                                </nav>
                            </div>
                            <p> <?php the_content(); ?></p>
                        </article>


    </div>

                <button class="close-button"><i class="fa fa-close"></i><span>Close</span></button>
</section>



 <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and the jquery code:

```
function loadContent(item) {


        var url = $(this).attr('href');
          history.pushState({}, '', url); //Add url to the href location when Colorbox is finished

        // add expanding element/placeholder 
        var dummy = document.createElement('div');
        dummy.className = 'placeholder';

        // set the width/heigth and position
        dummy.style.WebkitTransform = 'translate3d(' + (item.offsetLeft - 5) + 'px, ' + (item.offsetTop - 5) + 'px, 0px) scale3d(' + item.offsetWidth/gridItemsContainer.offsetWidth + ',' + item.offsetHeight/getViewport('y') + ',1)';
        dummy.style.transform = 'translate3d(' + (item.offsetLeft - 5) + 'px, ' + (item.offsetTop - 5) + 'px, 0px) scale3d(' + item.offsetWidth/gridItemsContainer.offsetWidth + ',' + item.offsetHeight/getViewport('y') + ',1)';

        // add transition class 
        classie.add(dummy, 'placeholder--trans-in');

        // insert it after all the grid items
        gridItemsContainer.appendChild(dummy);

        // body overlay
        classie.add(bodyEl, 'view-single');

        setTimeout(function() {
            // expands the placeholder
            dummy.style.WebkitTransform = 'translate3d(-5px, ' + (scrollY() - 5) + 'px, 0px)';
            dummy.style.transform = 'translate3d(-5px, ' + (scrollY() - 5) + 'px, 0px)';
            // disallow scroll
            window.addEventListener('scroll', noscroll);
        }, 25);

        onEndTransition(dummy, function() {
            // add transition class 
            classie.remove(dummy, 'placeholder--trans-in');
            classie.add(dummy, 'placeholder--trans-out');
            // position the content container
            contentItemsContainer.style.top = scrollY() + 'px';
            // show the main content container
            classie.add(contentItemsContainer, 'content--show');
            // show content item:
            classie.add(contentItems[current], 'content__item--show');
            // show close control
            classie.add(closeCtrl, 'close-button--show');
            // sets overflow hidden to the body and allows the switch to the content scroll
            classie.addClass(bodyEl, 'noscroll');

            isAnimating = false;
        });
    }
```

however, it shows the content only for the latest post but when i click on the other posts they are just empty.

Comment: This is because you are using the loop for the single page,
 which defaults to the current post. You need to use `WP_Query` or `query_posts` to query the posts you want, e.g. [Mastering WP_Query: Using the Loop](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mastering-wp_query-using-the-loop--cms-23031) If you do not understand the loop in Wordpress, please do some tutorials as it the basis of displaying content in WP.

Comment: @FluffyKitten thanks for the reply, can you check my edited question?

Comment: What are you passing in your `$args` array? That is the most important part as WP_Query will return the posts that match it.

Comment: @FluffyKitten anyway i fixed the $args thing but, you can check this here: http://www.canna-consulting.ca/ and see when you click on the first post it shows the content, but not for the other posts. its just empty.

Comment: Can you show us your `$args` array? As I said, thats the most relevant part so we can't try to help with your issue if we can't see where the problem lies.

Comment: and ignore all the above code, i will edit the entire question with the new code.

Comment: @FluffyKitten edited the whole question with the new code

Comment: You're still not showing us all the `$args` - what values are `$count` and `$paged`? You don't need to set `paged` in your case. Also, there are too many things going on to know where the problem is, so you need to break it down and go through it step-by-step. The first thing to do is forget about the jQuery and just get your loop working in standard php pages - don't even worry about css. Once thats working, you can add back the jQuery. In the pages, you only need to do WP_Query once - you only use it to search for posts. When you want to display a single post, you just use the standard loop.

Comment: @FluffyKitten yes i did it at first without any jquery or css. i did get_permalink and the posts displayed nicely as they should. but now (if you saw the link i posted above), i want the posts to display with the animations using jquery and all the proper styling. the thing is that the posts in this design are displaying in a AJAXy way and not normally as separate links. so after i implemented jquery, it shows only the content for the last post i have published and no content for the other posts. if i publish a new post, it will show only the content of the newest post.

Comment: It makes it very difficult to help when there is so much going on that we can't tell what's happening. I know you want the jQuery effects in the final site, but you need to get the basics working first. You should review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You need to get your single page PHP working before starting to include to with AJAX because that just makes it too difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: @FluffyKitten thanks for your time Kitten, i will go through this from scratch i think.

Comment: Sometimes thats the best approach, especially when you have gained new knowledge that will help you second time round :-) Good luck!